# "Unable to rollback to the current revision" when trying to rollback question revision

Tags: bug, revisions-list, rollbacks

I'm getting a `"Unable to rollback to the current revision"` alert box when clicking on the rollback option of the *revision 2* of the post below:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16379886/revisions

Update:
Right now, no error message is shown, but no rollback is made either.

@JasonC (comments) also reports a problem:
"Same issue trying to roll back to revision 4 of https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/251659/revisions (currently at revision 5)"

Comment: Something with the suggested edit being linked to the next edit (they improved it). Why they did that baffles me...

Comment: My best guess is that, since the suggested edit was never actually applied to the post, it was merged with the next edit. Since it was never applied, it can't be rolled back. Still, that's strange behavior...

Comment: @animuson Probably shouldn't have edited that post :/ now it's not reproducible here.

Comment: Yeah, and the latest editor didn't really added the "Thanks" back in. I believe their edits overlapped, that is, like @KnightswhosayNi said, the *revision 2* never really got through (@BobJarvis edited before it was approved).

Comment: @acdcjunior The edit was automatically approved when Bob Jarvis improved it, and marked the edit helpful. So, the edit was _technically_ approved, though it was never applied.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi Hm, I see! Now after @ animuson's edit, rollback on *revision 2* gives... nothing. Just a reload(?) on the page. Should we try to roll back to 3, then 2? I don't know, things are getting messy now... :(

Comment: @acdcjunior Can you still not rollback to 2?

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi Yes, when I click on *revision 2*'s rollback, the page is reloaded (some Ajax POSTs are made before the full reload) and nothing happens. Haven't tried to click on *revision 3*'s rollback, though.

Comment: That's _weird_. I just tested this, and I can't roll it back either. This is definitely reproducible.

Comment: Same issue trying to roll back to revision 4 of http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/251659/revisions (currently at revision 5).

Comment: What a strange, strange edit...

Comment: Tried rolling back http://stackoverflow.com/posts/834270/revisions from revision 3 to 2 but failed with same error message. Manually copied from 2 to make 4, then it allowed me to rollback from 4 to 2 which makes no changes.