# It's rather difficult to look over an answer that doesn't exist

Tags: bug, answers, review-audits, low-quality-posts

I just now failed an audit. When I went to review the audit, I was surprised to find it impossible to actually look over the answer. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Here you go.]

(Ha. Of course a nonexistent post contains nothing of value!)

I'm focusing on the part where it says:

> ...but please take a minute to look it over closely...

While normally I appreciate some helpful advice, it's not really effective if I'm not permitted to look again at the deleted answer. While this was likely a legitimate audit, I'd have liked to take another look. Deleted answers should stay *at least* until the user is done and has clicked the `I understand` button.

The audit link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/2051971). Screenshot follows of what a 10K+ user would see.

[image]

Comment: That's odd...I edited in a screenshot, but (even though I was told it needed to be reviewed), it instantly appeared and there's no edit history.

Comment: @Tim That is unnerving, and very likely related to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179073/unable-to-rollback-to-the-current-revision-when-trying-to-rollback-question-re)

Comment: I guess it's because I'm logged in...I see my edit to the post without any indication that it's actually pending. When I view the post anonymously, it appears in its original form. Confusing, though.

Comment: @TimMedora That's strange. You should have seen an edit pending banner

Comment: It looks like a real answer. Bad answers (which are still on topic) should be downvoted and not deleted, that is what I got the only time I flagged a bad answer for deletion. Though that link in the answer looks a bit off-topic/suspicious.

Comment: Taking another look, the answer is over 1 year and half late, the IDs in the answer are completely unrelated to the question just as the link.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure the link in the answer has little or nothing to do with the question. It looks like someone threw together an answer as a cover for spamming a link to their blog?

Comment: @TimMedora Agreed, the deletion by Community makes it even more suspicious.

Comment: Ach! What a clever disguise.

Comment: @Tim Medora: Yes - this is their only post with anything resembling meaningful content (i.e. a code block that looks like it would answer the question but doesn't really). They had numerous other answers that were **nothing but** "check out this site: <url>"

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi Sorry, my answer was aimed at listing why the review shouldn't have been failed rather than addressing the reported issue. I've retracted the answer as it isn't helpful in any way to your suggestion.

Comment: @slugster It's okay, it happens. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 7):

This was implemented last spring, with the following intended behavior:

- Moderators and [10K+](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) users can always see deleted posts used for review audits
- People who've *reviewed* audits based on deleted posts can always see them if they revisit the review task (they'll have to have saved a link to it somewhere).
- No one else can see the deleted posts used for audits, even with a link to the review task.

The flaw here is that there's an extra check in the template for answers that blocks the actual content from being rendered - as a result, you (the reviewer) get the sidebar and... Nothing else... Mods and 10K users see the actual post, while anyone else will see:

[image: unprivileged viewer sees "answer not found"]

A fix for this would require eliminating the second check when the answer is being rendered in /review.

Comment: FYI: I still have this error on the review audit I've linked.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of what you see when you follow the link?

Comment: 'Tis actually the same as the picture in the above post: http://imgur.com/psTYWFi

Comment: Ok - I see the problem now. Thanks!